# Like button not recording likes in the back end

Tags: django, django-views

Button successfully links back to current blog page but the likes are recording in the back end, what am I doing wrong here?

**views**

```
def BlogLike (request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=request.POST.get(slug))
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        return render(request, 'viewblog', {'post': post})
```

**urls**

```
path('view-blog/<slug:slug>/', views.ViewBlog, name='viewblog'),
path('like/<slug:slug>', views.BlogLike, name='likepost'),
```

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'viewblog' blog.slug %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 custom-button" id="like" type="sumbit" name="blog_id" value="{{ blog.slug }}">Like</button>
</form>
```

***EDIT***

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="",)
    text = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True, default="text")
    featured_text = models.TextField(max_length=550, null=True, blank=True, default="text")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: What do you mean "not recording likes in the backend"? What are the steps that you are following to produce this result? What is the actual result? How do you check if the like is recorded?

Comment: Also, please show enough code so we can understand everything involved. In particular, we will need to see your `BlogPost` model.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, likes now show under my blogpost model in admin. usernames should be highlighted when they click the like button, currently they do now highlight/record in database.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice models added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my functional code.

**views**

```
def BlogLike (request, slug):
        post_id = request.POST.get('blog-id')
        post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=post_id)
        post.likes.add(request.user)
    
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('viewblog', args=[post_id]))
```

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'likepost' blog.slug %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 custom-button" id="like" type="sumbit" name="blog-id" value="{{ blog.slug }}">Like<i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></button> - {{ blog.total_likes }} Likes
</form>
```

**urls**

```
 path('like/<slug:slug>', views.BlogLike, name='likepost'),
```

**models**

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')

  def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()   #this is to count amount of likes a post has.
```

Comment: Will you add some words to your code to describe what you changed to make it work?

Comment: As the previous answer said, you should use the `slug` from the URL instead of the POST body to determine which post to modify. The body is typically used to pass the data for the object, but not to identify which object to manipulate.